# Library or API interface with proper documentation for indoor localization using wifi,blutooth,cell id,rfid,gps?

Tags: java, android

Hi can anyone please tell me some java libraries or API interface with proper documentation for developing android application for indoor localization.I want to develop a android application which uses one or many technologies to find out your location accurately.

Waiting for the replies.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: there are no technologies that have been standardized yet. So unless you have access to hardware i dont think you can do it through app

Comment: but there are so many app's available in the market.I did not understand your answer.

Comment: you need to develop hardware which can send data to your app. So they would have developed the backend to implement it too

Comment: the hardware is already there in the phone,I want to use wifi,bluetooth,camera etc which is already there in the phone

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use wifi, bluetooth (camera ??) for localization, you need to connect the Smartphone (emettor) to the devices that will receive datas. Then it has to compute triangulation from received datas. Yet wifi isn't the good technology for it (norms, bandwith, precision, interferences, ...) Google is working on it, as well as IBM, redwood hat, among others... but lacks precision and efficience. You need specific Radio frequency devices (emettor/receiver) meshed together to cover an area. then apply results of algorythms to polygoned maps... 
no apps for it.

Comment: thanks for the answer do you have any idea how can i do it.If you can give me some hints it will be very useful for my work.Thanks!!